# dotnet 3.1: ChangePasswordAsync give Password Mismatch while CheckPasswordAsync accepts the same password

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am working on a section in my app where users can update their password. I created a method for this in my authentication service.

`AuthenticationService.cs`

```
[Authorize]
public async Task ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
{
    // Need to get it this way otherwise the ChangePasswordAsync won't accept this user
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(_userService.CurrentUser.Id);

    var result = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user, model.CurrentPassword, model.NewPassword);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

The `userService.CurrentUser` is a getter which get's the user from the `IdentityDbContext` using their JWT. I debugged and this returned the right user / ID.

I call this from my `AuthenticationController.cs`

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        await _authenticationService.ChangePassword(model);

        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return BadRequest(new ErrorViewModel()
        {
            ErrorKey = "error_changing_password"
        });
    }
}
```

`ChangePasswordViewModel.cs`

```
public class ChangePasswordViewModel
{
    public string CurrentPassword { get; set; }

    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
}
```

But for some reason the `ChangePasswordAsync` returns this error: `"PasswordMismatch"`. I am absolutely positive that this password IS right. I log in with it through the same `UserManager`:

```
await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password)
```

Any idea why the `ChangePasswordAsync` is giving me this feedback while `CheckPasswordAsync` returns a positive result? Am I allowing faulty passwords? We only set passwords through the `UserManager` using the `CreateAsync` (on creation) or using the `ResetPasswordAsync` with a generated token.

Comment: You can put `await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.CurrentPassword)` in your `ChangePassword` method before `result ` to see if it true.

Comment: @Yinqiu I've done this and the weirdest thing happened. When I have the `CheckPasswordAsync` above the `ChangePasswordAsync` it DOES work. It changes the password. When I comment it out and compile again the `ChangePasswordAsync` fails. I'm guessing the `CheckPasswordAsync` modifies the `user` but doesn't tell this in the documentation.

Comment: You can try to add this code `await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);` after ChangePassword.